# Update value according to subquery

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

Trying to update `'_stock'` `meta_value` according to the `'post_id'` found by looking for the `_sku`.

```
   +---------+---------+----------+---------------+
    | meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value    |
    +---------+---------+----------+---------------+
    | 2922    | 161     | _sku     | VISHID-116E   |
    +---------+---------+----------+---------------+
    | 2955    | 162     | _sku     | VISHID-4402   |
    +---------+---------+----------+---------------+
    | 2889    | 160     | _sku     | VISCTL-EPX960 |
    +---------+---------+----------+---------------+
    | 2894    | 160     | _stock   | 1             |
    +---------+---------+----------+---------------+
    | 2927    | 161     | _stock   | 1             |
    +---------+---------+----------+---------------+
    | 2960    | 162     | _stock   | 1             |
    +---------+---------+----------+---------------+
```

The select function works:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key= '_stock' 
AND post_id=(SELECT post_id FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_value = 'VISHID-116E')
```

[DEMO Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c7fdec/4)

But the update query doesn't:

```
UPDATE  wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value= '230'
WHERE meta_key= '_stock' 
AND post_id="(SELECT post_id FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_value = 'VISHID-116E')"
```

---

### EDIT

Here's what I came up with after the advice given below:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta,

    (SELECT post_id, qty
    FROM
        (SELECT meta_value as `sku`, post_id as `post_id`
        FROM `wp_postmeta` 
        WHERE meta_key="_sku") as a
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT qty, part
        FROM `stock`) as b
    ON a.sku=b.part) src

SET wp_postmeta.meta_value=src.qty
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key="_stock"
AND wp_postmeta.post_id=src.post_id
```

This should be helpful for developers working with WooCommerce who are trying to update stock qty from another table.

Comment: If you put it in quotation marks, then it's a string, right?

Comment: It gives me an error when I remove the quotation marks: "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'wp_postmeta' for update in FROM clause"

I have a feeling I need to run this before the update...

Comment: what is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: Well, that's not really an argument for wrapping it in quotation marks now is it! ;-) But +1 for the fiddle.

Comment: Well, with the quotes, it would say "0 updated".
Without the quotes, it gives the following error: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'wp_postmeta' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `UPDATE` query to be either of below

Using `INNER JOIN`

```
UPDATE  wp_postmeta 
inner join
(SELECT post_id 
             FROM `wp_postmeta` 
             WHERE meta_value = 'VISHID-116E'
) tab on wp_postmeta.post_id = tab.post_id
SET meta_value= '230'
WHERE meta_key= '_stock'
```

Using `SubQuery`

```
UPDATE  wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value= '230'
WHERE meta_key= '_stock' 
AND post_id = (SELECT post_id FROM 
(
select post_id FROM `wp_postmeta` 
WHERE meta_value = 'VISHID-116E'
) tab
)
```

Your posted fiddle with modification http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a929af/1

Comment: I actually used your `INNER JOIN` concept.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta x
  JOIN wp_postmeta y
    ON y.post_id = x.post_id
   SET x.meta_value = 230
 WHERE x.meta_key= '_stock' 
   AND y.meta_value = 'VISHID-116E'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d468e/1

Answer (score 0):

Mysql is a bit retarded when trying to update,you have to do it in a convoluted way if you dont use Joins.

```
UPDATE  wp_postmeta 
SET meta_value= '230'
WHERE meta_key= '_stock' 
AND post_id=(SELECT post_id FROM(SELECT post_id FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE meta_value = 'VISHID-116E')x)
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed9522/1)